# TDS code generation in sitecore using TextTransform.exe

Tags: sitecore, code-generation, t4, .net-standard, tds

I am working on Code Generation Template using TDS in sitecore 8.2 update 4 and I am using these .tt file https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/tds-codegen/tree/master/Sitecore.Master/Code%20Generation%20Templates. I want to generate code using TextTransform.exe in batch file so what is correct way? Please guide me..

Comment: Are you using TDS? Any reason you do not want to use TDS for Code Generation?

Comment: I am using Helix framework so there are so many project and I have to regenerate every project so I want to do code regenerate at the time of build so it will regenerate code for all project

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into reverse engineering the TDS DLL files.

The main file which is doing code generation is HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP2015.dll in D:\Program Files (x86)\Hedgehog Development\Team Development for Sitecore (VS2015).

The main entry for code generation should be in Manager class, however I'm not sure about that.